# PHP mail function - Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu

I need some help. It is all about the **PHP mail function in ubuntu** since when i accessing it through **browser it returns false**, but when i accessing it **through command line it works**. I am using postfix. Why is it? Thank You in advance.

```
<?php 
$res = mail ( "test@gmail.com", "Test from de lappie..." , "Hello World!" ); 
var_export( $res ); 
?>
```

- when accessing it through browser. the browser displays "false",
- when accessing it command line "php /var/www/adm/test.php" it works, i receive the mail.

Comment: Any codes?? What worked and how and what doesn't work ?? What command line you tried.

Comment: here is my code , test.php ->                                         <?php
$res = mail ( "test@gmail.com", "Test from de lappie..." , "Hello World!" );
var_export( $res );
?>                                                                                                      when accessing it through browser. the browser displays "false", when accessing it command line "php /var/www/adm/test.php" it works, i receive the mail.

Comment: Plz update your question. its not easy to read here in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has seperate ini files depending on the enviorment.

You need to make some changes to the configuration files

```
cli/php.ini
cgi/php.ini
php.ini
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590934/php-sendmail-works-in-ubuntu-command-line-but-not-from-a-php-file) for the detailed information